# PLS-00103 error when using COMMENT statement in BEGIN ... END block in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pls-00103

Out of curiosity I'm attempting to use the COMMENT statement in a PL/SQL block. I'm using Oracle APEX 18.2 on an Oracle 11g database and in SQL Workshop I am able to execute the command by itself, but if I wrap it in a BEGIN ... END block then I get an error message like:

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ON" when expecting one of the following: : = . ( @ % ;
```

Example of command that works:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN employees.job_id IS 'comment';
```

Example of command that results in the error message:

```
BEGIN  
    COMMENT ON COLUMN employees.job_id IS 'comment';  
END;
```

I assume that COMMENT isn't a permitted statement in a stored procedure but I haven't been able to find evidence to back this up. Am I correct and if so is this documented anywhere?

Thanks to @GMB for an answer with written example.

Comment: Have you tried using `execute immediate 'COMMENT ON COLUMN employees.job_id IS ''comment'''` . It is DDL and it must be performed using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in PL/SQL block

Comment: Thank you very much @Tejash - I hadn't done that and wasn't aware of it!

Comment: Basically, the COMMENT command is a DDL statement, which cannot be executed directly within PL/SQL.

Comment: The PL/SQL language has no 'comment' keyword, hence the syntax error. You would get the same error for 'banana'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
create table employees(job_id int);

begin  
    comment on column employees.job_id is 'comment'
end;
/
```

```
ora-06550: line 2, column 13:
pls-00103: encountered the symbol "on" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
```

```
begin  
    execute immediate 'comment on column employees.job_id is ''comment''' ;
end;
/
```

```
1 rows affected
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6052a08f1fa2fcf06287d77960efee6)*